# how can I detect the difference between real face and fake face using ai

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, face-detection, face-recognition

I have built model that can know who is in the photo taken by camera , but It couldn't detect is it real person taken the photo or it was taken from saved photo like mobile screen or computer or printed photo.
Can anybody help me to detect the difference using ai?

Comment: Take a look at the following [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-10-minutes-with-mnist-dataset-54c35b77a38d) to get starting with building a Neural Network using the Keras library in Python

Comment: You want to detect images that are screenshots and mark them as "fake"?

Comment: This is not trivial at all. You are aware you could easily build a graduate thesis and a few papers out of this problem, right?

Comment: you could try to detect special fake face layer material. Like a video image that captures an lcd screen might have some flickering. A video image of a paper picture might give some apecial shiny look, etc. But all rhis wont be an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Image Classifier. However, you need to make a dataset of what you believe are real faces and fake faces.